# port number in the application URL changes when using send.Redirect from code

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere-8

I am observing a strange behavior in our application in a prod environment. Our Spring MVC app is deployed in WebSphere 8.We are redirecting page after user login successful to the home page. However in prod the port number in URL changes to a different one.

For Instance.

Login URL: http://myapp:5555/login.

Redirecting using : `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/homePage");`

After Login successfully URL becomes: http://myapp:33889/homePage. Ideally, it should be http://myapp:5555/homePage :(.

Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously your configuration of the redirect is changing the port number.  Check your server configuration and your Java code (which you haven't shown) to see why this is happening.  Nobody here is going to be able to magically look into your server and see what you've configured/coded.

Comment: Jim, the java code we use to redirect is  response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/homePage");.This is normal page redirection, hope you know this.As you said if its server issue we would like to know which configuration we need to cross check since we are not WebSphere experts.

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a WebSphere expert who can examine your configuration.  Time to hire a consultant.

Comment: Your question is off-topic unless you can post enough information to make it answerable.

Comment: Ideally, your DEV and PROD configuration should be the same. Isn't that really the issue if DEV behaves one way and PROD is different behavior?